# How to assert multiple facts or rules in one assert/1 statement?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

If I'm at the repl I can do

```
?- assert(foo(a)),assert(foo(b)),assert(foo(c)).
```

and that works, but not

```
?- assert((bar(a),bar(b),bar(c))).
```

or similar. Is there a way to only need to type "assert" once and pass in multiple facts? Same question for rules.

thanks!

I tried several variations of what I mentioned above to accomplish this but can't figure out how to do it. Also looked at the doc for assert/1 but it doesn't show how.

Comment: *Why* do you want to specify multiple facts in the same `assert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can instead consult from *user*?

```
?- [user].
:- dynamic(foo/1).
foo(a).
foo(b).
foo(c).
```

Press Ctrl-D to end consulting. If you just want to add clauses the database, you may not need to type the `dynamic/1` directive.

P.S. `assert/1` is a deprecated/legacy predicate. Use instead `assrta/1` or `assertz/1` if you must.

Comment: Ok, woah... did not know about [user]. Yep, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!! Anymore repl environments like this I should be aware of?